# What activation function on the last layer and loss function should I use in an auto encoder for reconstructing a sequence of events? [Keras]

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, time-series, autoencoder

My data set is a 3D array of the size (M,t,N) where M is the number of samples, t is the number of timesteps in a sequence and N is the number of possible events that can happen at time t. By selecting a specific M we have a 2D array of size (t,N) where each row is a timestep and each column is an event. Each column is set to 1 if that event happened at time t, otherwise it's set to 0. Only 1 event can happen at any given timestep.

I want to try and build an auto-encoder for anomaly detection, and in the tutorials and blogs I have read, the last activation layer is 'relu' and the loss function is 'mse'. But since I am trying to basically reconstruct a classification with N classes, would 'softmax' as the last layer and 'categorical_crossentropy' be better?

```
inputs = Input(shape = (timesteps,n_features))
# Encoder
lstm_enc_1 = LSTM(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(timesteps, n_features), return_sequences=True)(inputs)
lstm_enc_2 = LSTM(latent_dim, activation='relu', return_sequences=False)(lstm_enc_1)
repeater = RepeatVector(timesteps)
# Decoder
lstm_dec_1 = LSTM(latent_dim, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)
lstm_dec_2 = LSTM(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)
time_dis = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_features,activation='softmax')) #<-- Does this make sense here?

z = repeater(lstm_enc_2)
h = lstm_dec_1(z)
decoded_h = lstm_dec_2(h)
decoded = time_dis(decoded_h)

ae = Model(inputs,decoded)
ae.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam') #<-- Does this make sense here?
```

Or should I, for some reason, still use 'relu' and 'mse' as the last activation function and loss function?

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When i read it correctly, N is one-hot encoded and it sounds like you want to do a classification, no regression.

For beeing y one-hot encoded, using categorical_crossentropy is correct.
If you have more classes in y than 4, you may use integer-encodings and use sparse_categorical_crossentropy, which decodes you y values to one-hot matrices on the way.

mse is better used for regression.

As last actication, since you have a classification, you may want to use softmax, which outputs a probability for each of your y classes.

As far as I know, your normally do not use relu is the last layer, if you have a regression task, you prefer sigmoid in general.

Comment: Hi, since it's an autoencoder I don't really have any "y". In this case, Y=X since I am trying to reconstruct the input. So the number of classes is N here, which is >50 in this case.

Comment: So what does the training say?

Comment: Not sure I understod that last comment, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Did you start training the model and saw its outcome?
Because basically, both of your questions in your code can be answered with yes, it makes sense. So train it and see if it works